# "I just ate a few minutes ago"

Tags: grammar, word-requests

When a friend asks if you want to go to dinner, but have already eaten, then you say "もう食べた".

Is there a way of saying "just ate" (a few minutes ago). Maybe it is another way of saying もう食べた

Comment: Related/duplicate of: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/verbs-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D-verbs-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93-verbs-%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A

Answer (score 4):

「食べたばかりです」

More information [here](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/timeaction2.html#part2)

Comment: You can also add `先` for additional emphasis.

Comment: ^ `先` >> You probably mean 「さっき」？ (or ついさっき)

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> 今食べたところ（だ・です）

This literally means "I just ate".

I think it's a little more neutral than 食べたばかり（だ・です）.

ばかり feels more like "I can't/won't eat any more" where ところ feels more like "I just had dinner".

Answer (score 1):

済ませました、済ませてしまいました: This phrase is a little polite.

もう食べちゃった　：　This phrase is very frank,usually used it to friends or family.