# なきゃ and とこ usage and translation

Tags: translation, manga, reading-comprehension

I've come across this conversation in それでも歩は寄せてくる:
[image]

This is the transcript:

> 田中歩：「何してるんですか」
> 八乙女うるし：「お 田中 いいとこに来たな」
> 八乙女うるし：「新入部員も入ったことだし 名前を入れてやらなきゃなーって 今書いてんだ」

I'm having trouble with Urushi's sentence:

1. I think the first sentence translates as "You came at a good time" or something like that but I've never seen とこ being used to indicate a moment in time. Is this correct or am I getting it wrong?
2. Basically it seems she is saying that since someone joined their club his name is missing from the sign and she is adding it now. What I don't understand is the second part of the sentence:

   > 「名前を**入れてやらなきゃなーって**今書いてんだ」

   I understand last part about writing the name and the explanatory んだ. What I don't get is the part in bold. This is how I understand it now:

   - 「入れて」 is 入れる which means "to insert" which is put in て-form for progressive state.
   - 「やらなきゃな」 is やる which is the casual form of する, in the あ-stem for use with the negative なければ which means "if not" which is contracted to なきゃ. So the whole thing means "if not do".  I'm assuming the な is for emphasis and isn't negation or imperative command.
   - 「って」 here plays the role of は as in marking the topic of the sentence.

   So the whole thing should translate "If is not in state of being inserted".

   Thus the whole sentence should translate as "As for the name of the new club member not being inserted, I'm writing it now". The thing is I don't see how the なきゃ part comes into play in this translation.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me make sense of these sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This とこ is a colloquial variant of ところ, which is a very flexible noun that means not only "place" but also "time", "situation", "aspect" and so on. Haven't you seen [these patterns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2681/5010) where ところ refers to something related to time or moment?
- Yes, 入れて is the te-form of 入れる ("to put in"), but why "progressive"? The te-form does not express the progressive aspect on its own.
- This やる is not する, but an informal and less polite variant of [あげる](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/kureru-ageru-morau/). やる and あげる are [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010), i.e., it has a special function after a te-form. As you may already know, (-て)やる and (-て)あげる are notoriously difficult to translate directly, but here it's basically just "for them (the new members)".
- You're correct that なきゃ is contracted なければ. A super-literal translation of 名前を入れてやらなきゃ is "if I don't give (a favor of) putting a name". But なければ, なくては, なきゃ and so on can effectively mean "have to".
- This って is not a topic particle but a quotative particle used without an explicit verb. Here something like 思って is implied. See: [verb+ようにと、 or verb+かと、](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21680/5010)

Here's a translation (added punctuations for clarity):

> 新入部員も入ったことだし、「名前を入れてやらなきゃなー」って(思って)、今書いてんだ。
>
> Now that the new club members joined, I thought "I gotta put their names (for the sake of them)", so I'm writing them now.